# Sphinx - Cannot use field attribute in query

Tags: sphinx

I cannot use @field-name in my sphinx query, but I can use @*

I could use the @field-name attribute when querying the test.documents example, but not for another table I have indexed.

This is my PHP:

```
    require_once('sphinxapi.php');
    $this->sphinx = new SphinxClient;
    $this->sphinx->setServer("localhost", 9312);
    $this->sphinx->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);

    //This works:
    $result = $this->sphinx->query("@* bob");
    var_dump($result);

    //This doesn't work:
    $result = $this->sphinx->query("@artist bob");
    var_dump($result);
```

Output of: /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --all --rotate --dump-rows sphinxrows.txt

```
# === source src1 ts 1318588067
# Fri Oct 14 10:27:47 2011
#
# field 0: name
# field 1: filename
# field 2: artist
# sql_attr_uint = id_attr # attr 0
# sql_attr_timestamp = date_added # attr 1
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rows_src1;
CREATE TABLE rows_src1 (
  id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  id_attr VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL,
  date_added VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL,
  filename VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL,
  artist VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL,
  KEY(id) );

INSERT INTO rows_src1 VALUES ('6', '6', '0', 'track 1 title', 'track-1.wav', 'bob');
INSERT INTO rows_src1 VALUES ('70', '70', '0', 'track 2 title', 'track-2.wav', 'eric');
```

Sphinx.conf:

```
source src1
{
        type                    = mysql

        sql_query               = \
                SELECT id, id AS id_attr, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, name, filename, artist \
                FROM files

        sql_attr_uint           = id_attr
        sql_attr_timestamp      = date_added

        sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM files WHERE id=$id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field names need to be defined in sphinx.conf. Adding an entry for "rt_field" solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

In sql you have "rows_src1"  table , in sphinx.conf you have "files" as table

Comment: rows_src1 is the Sphinx indexer table, files is my table that I have asked it to index. I figured out the problem, you need to add an "rt_field" in sphinx.conf for the fields you wish to use in a query.